# Skipping loop iteration in Javascript - can't get it to work correctly

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to execute a statement in a loop, only if all previous conditions aren't met and don't return (ending the iteration). But the statement is executing even though the loop has apparently ended its iteration.

This is all happening in the 'parse' method in the 'catagorize words' section. The statement I only want to execute if other conditions don't apply is the 'Add uncatagorized' statement. I haven't included the object that contains the 'items' as it's got a lot of other stuff you don't need to see. But in case you do it can be found here: [Link](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/textadventure-rewrite?path=public/client.js:1:0)

```js
var textParser4 = {
  // It need to store command phrases
  commandWords: ["north", "pick up", "east", "south", "west", "up", "down", "examine", "open", "inventory", "use", "get", "take", "drop", "put dn"],
    // It needs to store filler words - to remove
  fillerWords: ["go", "to", "then", "with", "it", "at", "as", "and", "i"],
  // It needs to store string after it's turned into array
  stringArray: [],
  // It needs somewhere to store seperated strings
  seperateStringArrays: [],
  // It needs a parsing function
  parse: function(inputString) {
     // It needs to make input string lower case.
     inputString = inputString.toLowerCase();
     // It needs to remove punctuation
    inputString = inputString.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");
    // It needs to remove filler words.
    this.fillerWords.forEach(function(word) {
      inputString = inputString.replace(word + " ", "");
    });
    // Turn string into array
    this.stringArray = inputString.split(" ");
    // Remove empty elements
    this.stringArray.forEach(function(element, index) {
      if (element === "") {
        this.stringArray.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }, this);
    // Catagorise words
    for (var i = 0; i < this.stringArray.length; i++) {
      console.log("string array length: ", this.stringArray.length);
      var jWord = this.stringArray[i] + " " + this.stringArray[i + 1];
      this.commandWords.forEach(function(cWord) {
        //find two word commands first
        if (cWord === jWord) {
          this.seperateStringArrays.push({ phrase: this.stringArray[i]  + " " +  this.stringArray[i + 1], wordCatagory: "command" });
          // Remove word that has been joined with previous word
          this.stringArray.splice(i + 1, 1);
          return;
          // find single word commands
        } else if (cWord === this.stringArray[i]) {
          this.seperateStringArrays.push({ phrase: this.stringArray[i], wordCatagory: "command" });
        }
        return;
        // find items words
      }, this);
      // find items
      Game.items.forEach(function(item) {
        if (jWord === item.name) {
          // find two word items
          this.seperateStringArrays.push( { phrase: this.stringArray[i]  + " " +  this.stringArray[i + 1], wordCatagory: "item" });
          // Remove word that has been joined with previous word
          this.stringArray.splice(i + 1, 1);
          return;
          // find single word items
        } else if (this.stringArray[i] === item.name) {
          this.seperateStringArrays.push({ phrase: this.stringArray[i], wordCatagory: "item" });
        }
        return;
      }, this);
      // Add uncatagorised 
      this.seperateStringArrays.push({ phrase: this.stringArray[i], wordCatagory: "uncatagorized" });
    };
    // DOn't forget to empty string array after new arrays are created
    console.log(this.seperateStringArrays);
    // sort sentences into seperate commands
    this.seperateStringArrays = [];
  }
}

// catagorise word
// loop through string array
// check if word or pair of words match a command
  // If so, end iteration and start next
// Check if word or word pair match an item
  // If so, end iteration and start next iteration
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not missing something, this line of code:

```
this.seperateStringArrays.push({ phrase: this.stringArray[i], wordCatagory: "uncatagorized" });
```

is running outside of the forEach iteration, so it will obviously keep executing once the iteration is done, to solve this problem; try to put it as an `else if` within the loop and place it at the bottom of the loop, since any other statement that evaluates to `true` will return out of the loop and break before reaching it.

```
  Game.items.forEach(function(item) {
    if (jWord === item.name) {
      // find two word items
      this.seperateStringArrays.push( { phrase: this.stringArray[i]  + " " +  this.stringArray[i + 1], wordCatagory: "item" });
      // Remove word that has been joined with previous word
      this.stringArray.splice(i + 1, 1);
      return;
      // find single word items
    } else if (this.stringArray[i] === item.name) {
      this.seperateStringArrays.push({ phrase: this.stringArray[i], wordCatagory: "item" });
    }
    //End of if statement
    return;
  }, this);
  //End of forEach
this.seperateStringArrays.push({ phrase: this.stringArray[i], wordCatagory: "uncatagorized" });
```

Comment: No, I have just checked this and it isn't. You can see the end of the forEach loop above, unless Glitch is telling me lies. The statement in question is right before the end of the for loop.

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not fixing my problem. I've re-written it using .map instead. It's a lot cleaner, it's just not returning properly yet.